# ラズベリーパイにて、systemdを使った自動起動プログラムの場合にのみエラーが発生します。

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, systemd

#### 質問の概要

ラズベリーパイにてPython3を使用中です。
毎日の終わりに一度、
「センサの値をテキストファイルに書き込み、添付ファイル付きのメールを送るプログラム」
を実装済みです。
手動で実行するとエラーは発生しませんが、systemdを用いて電源ON時に自動起動を行うとエラーが発生します。
以下に詳しく記載します。

#### エラー詳細

発生しているエラーは
「メール送信を実行するとプログラミングが止まる」
です。
前述の通り、手動（Thonnyからやターミナルからの実行）ではメール送信も出来ますが
systemd を用いた.timerファイルと.serviceファイルを使う方式に変えると、メール送信実行時に止まります。

ラズパイのログを見ると以下のエラーメッセージがありました。（/var/log/syslog）

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Leasemat2/CClite.py", line 198, in <module>
SDATT.send_emailATT(RECIPIENT,Title,Bodytext,Attfile)
File "/home/pi/Leasemat2/SendMailATT.py", line 45, in send_emailATT
server.send_message(msg)
AttributeError: SMTP instance has no attribute 'send_message'
leasemat02.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
leasemat02.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

添付ファイルのメールを送信するモジュールでエラーが起こっているようですが
・単体での動作は正常（メール送信可能）
・プログラム全体（メインプログラムからのモジュールのコール）でも、手動での実行では正常
です。

#### ソースコード

Python3での記述です。
添付ファイルを送るモジュールのソースコードは以下です。
日付をファイル名にしています

```
# coding: UTF-8
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
import time
import datetime

# SMTP認証情報
account = '*****@gmail.com'
password = '*****'

# 送受信先
from_email = "****@xxx.xxx"
RECIPIENT = '*****@xxx.xxx'

def send_emailATT(recipient,title,text,fliepath): #recipient:受取人
    # MIMEの作成
    subject = title
    message = text
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["To"] = recipient
    msg["From"] = from_email
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))


    # ファイルを添付
    path = fliepath # "./readme.txt"
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        part = MIMEApplication(
            f.read(),
            Name=basename(path)
        )

    part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(path)
    msg.attach(part)
    # メール送信処理
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(account, password)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':


    place ='xxxx'
    Title = 'Location is {}'.format(place[:])

    num = 0
    Bodytext = 'Test is {}'.format(num)

    stmp = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    Attfile =  './'+stmp+ '.txt'

    send_emailATT(RECIPIENT,Title,Bodytext,Attfile)
```

#### 最後に

ここが原因と気づくのに色々と試した結果、systemdが悪さをしていると気づきました。
Linux系は勉強を始めたばかりなので、アドバイスを頂けると幸いです。

Comment: SMTPクラスにsend_messageメソッド追加されたのは python 3.2以降です。systemd の `.service` ファイルの具体的な内容を確認する必要がありますが、もしかすると PATH の設定などで当該のスクリプトが python2 で実行されているのかもしれません。

Comment: 仰っる通りでした。　.serviceファイルの記述をpython3にすると実行できました。

Comment: 本当にありがとうございました。とても悩んでいたので本当に助かりました。